# Adjust side-by-side equations to the center and their equation number to the right

Tags: equations, align, alignment, subequations, aligned

Consider the following example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align}
    a_j = 
    \begin{cases}
    2, & {\rm~if~} j = n, \\
    1, & {\rm~if~} j = n - 1, \\
    j - 1, & {\rm otherwise}
    \end{cases}
    \end{align}
    %
    and
    %
    \begin{align}
    b_j = 
    \begin{cases}
    1, & {\rm~if~} j > n - 2, \\
    0, & {\rm otherwise}.
    \end{cases}
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

In this example, I would like to have the two equations in the following format:

[image]

Here the equation number should be aligned to the right margin, while all the other items (the two equations and the "and" word) should be centered. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: replace `\end{align}
    %
    and
    %
    \begin{align}` by `\text{ and }` and the outer `align` by `equation`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most simple way to do this is using the `equation` environment, the command `\text{}` to write texts inside the equations and use `\quad` or `\qquad` to make spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{your label}
    a_j = 
    \begin{cases}
        2, & \text{if } j = n, \\
        1, & \text{if } j = n - 1, \\
        j - 1, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases} 
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
    b_j = 
    \begin{cases}
        1, & \text{if } j > n - 2, \\
        0, & \text{otherwise}.
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please also replace `{\rm~if~}` and `{\rm otherwise}` with `\text{if }` and `\text{otherwise}`, respectively.

Answer (score 5):

The `flalign` works same way as `align` with exception that it pushes everything towards left/right margins if that is your goal:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}


\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
    & a_j = 
    \begin{cases}
    2, & {\rm~if~} j = n, \\
    1, & {\rm~if~} j = n - 1, \\
    j - 1, & {\rm otherwise}
    \end{cases}
    & \text{and} &&
    b_j = 
    \begin{cases}
    1, & {\rm~if~} j > n - 2, \\
    0, & {\rm otherwise}.
    \end{cases} \hspace{1em} & % Additional space before eq. no.
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

[image]